# Spring boot: What is the right way to seed the databse?

Tags: database, spring, h2, seeding

I have a Spring Boot application and would like to seed the database the first time the application runs, but not every time the application runs, and then only if the data does not already exist.

My application has a **data.sql** file and I have it inserting the default users:

```
-- insert the administrator
INSERT INTO users(id, username, password_hash, email, first_name, last_name) VALUES
  (1, 'admin', 'comixed', 'email1@domain.com', 'ComixEd', 'Administrator'),
  (2, 'user', 'comixeduser', 'email2@domain.com', 'ComixEd', 'User')
;

-- insert the supported roles
INSERT INTO roles(id, name) VALUES
  (1, 'Administrator'),
  (2, 'User')
;

-- set the administrator roles
INSERT INTO users_roles(user_id, role_id) VALUES
  (1, 1),
  (1, 2),
  (2, 2)
;
```

But Spring is obviously trying to run this file every time I start the app. And when it does an exception is raised since the users and roles are already in the database.

What's a better way to do this? And, optionally, what's a way to add new seed data if, in future, new features require new roles, etc.?

Comment: Maybe you should try a higher database migration tool like Flyway or Liquibase [(relevant documentation)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-use-a-higher-level-database-migration-tool).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flyway is what you are looking for https://flywaydb.org/

It is a database migration tool that can be used to create and modify databases in a project. It creates its own table in your schema and adds the script name and a checksum value into the tables. During application boot it scans the scripts, checks to see if they're in the table and if the checksums match still. This makes sure the files don't change and everything has been migrated.

Comment: That's more along the lines of what I'm wanting. It sounds similar to how Rails migrations work. Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

You have to configure it in the `application.properties` file.
Add this line and it should work as you wish:
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update`

Comment: I'm not asking how to create the tables, but how to put data into the tables after they're created. Your solution doesn't address that problem.

Comment: I'm sorry I missed part of the solution. The way I've done that before is writing the `inserts` in a file called `import.sql`, placed at the same folder level  as `application.properties`. Spring automatically looks for that specific file to do the seeding. You might find this useful https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Comment: The import.sql file is done with every run of the application. I was looking for a solution that would only run the import once since I'm only looking to seed the database initially.

Comment: Then, in `application.properties` you have to configure the property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop`, run the project, and change it to `none` or `update` afterwards, so it doesn't do the process again. Again, I suggest reading the docs.

Comment: That's not at all what I'm trying to do.

What I want it for the app, the first time it runs, to seed the database after creation. Not drop tables and recreate them since the user's are going to have persistent data.

Specifically what I was trying to do was create a default user account to be used to log into the application when it's first installed. After that the users can't change the login details however they like. 

Flyway does what I want. I appreciate your input but you don't seem to understand the problem I was trying to solve.

Comment: @mcpierce this seems to be an old post but were you able to solve the problem and if yes then can you please share it. I am now in the same boat as you.

Comment: @Amit Yes, what I ended up doing is adding Liquibase to my project and depending on it to manage the schema and to perform migrations and seeding of tables. My reply above mentioned FlywayDB but we abandoned that and went to Liquibase shortly after I posted it.